# 'User' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, html, django

I created a form to set let the user changes their password, but I got this message: 'User' object is not subscriptable.
I'd like to know how to change it properly.

here's the part of my code.

view.py

```
def alterar_senha(request, user_username):
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = AlterarSenha()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'usuarios/administrativo/alterar_senha.html', context)
elif request.method == 'POST':
    usuario = User.objects.get(username=user_username)
    form = AlterarSenha(request.POST)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    senha = request.POST.get('password')
    senha1 = request.POST.get('new_password1')
    senha2 = request.POST.get('new_password2')

    print(senha1, senha2)

    if not usuario.check_password(senha):
        form.add_error('password', 'Senha inválida!')

    id = usuario.id
    if form.is_valid():
        user = usuario[id]
        user.set_password('senha')
        user.save()
        return redirect('logout')
    else:
        print(form.errors)

    return render(request, 'usuarios/administrativo/alterar_senha.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
class AlterarSenha(forms.Form):
password = forms.CharField(label='Senha atual', widget=forms.PasswordInput(
    attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': "Digite sua senha",
        'name': 'senha1'
    }
))

new_password1 = forms.CharField(label='Nova senha', widget=forms.PasswordInput(
    attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': "Digite sua senha",
        'name': 'password1'
    }
))

new_password2 = forms.CharField(label='Repita a Senha', widget=forms.PasswordInput(
    attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': "Digite novamente",
        'name': 'password1'
    }
))

def clean(self):
    new_password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password1')
    new_password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_password2')

    lista_erros = {}

    checa_senha(new_password1, new_password2, lista_erros)

    if lista_erros is not None:
        for erro in lista_erros:
            mensagem_erro = lista_erros[erro]
            self.add_error(erro, mensagem_erro)
    return self.cleaned_data

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = User.objects.create_user(
        password=self.cleaned_data['new_password1']
    )
    return user
```

html page

```
<form action="{% url 'alterar_senha' user.username %}" method="POST">

<div class="container center_div">
<div class="col-12 col-lg-10">
    {{form.password.label_tag}}
    {{form.password}}
</div>

{% for error in form.password.errors %}
    <section class="alert alert-danger col-12" role="alert">
        {{ form.password.errors }}
    </section>
{% endfor %}

<div class="col-12 col-lg-10">
    {{form.new_password1.label_tag}}
    {{form.new_password1}}
</div>

{% for error in form.new_password1.errors %}
    <section class="alert alert-danger col-12" role="alert">
        {{ form.new_password1.errors }}
    </section>
{% endfor %}

<div class="col-12 col-lg-10">
    {{form.new_password2.label_tag}}
    {{form.new_password2}}
</div>

</div>

<div class="d-flex p-2 bd-highlight">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-green" type="submit">Salvar</button>
        {% csrf_token %}
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

I tried reading the django documentation but there's only the form they've created, which I wouldn't like to use. Hope anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this block:

```
    id = usuario.id #Delete
if form.is_valid():
    user = usuario[id] #Delete
    user.set_password('senha')
    user.save()
    return redirect('logout')
```

with this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    userio.set_password('senha')
    userio.save()
    return redirect('logout')
```

Comment: I just did. But still, can't change the password.

Comment: The error changed yes? There may be some other issue in your script, but the subscriptable part was the userio['accessor']. What's the new error? --- also, kind of hard without seeing your user class.

Comment: if your userio has a user object in it with the appropriate id, can you call userio.set_password('password') on it otherwise userio.objects.set(password='password') may work

Comment: Actually the error is still the same. TypeError: 'User' object is not subscriptabl

Comment: I'll try the second option then.
p.s. I tried. Now the error is: Manager isn't accessible via User instances

Comment: So, the revised way is essentially carbon-copy from Django auth documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#topics-auth-changing-passwords.  ---- advise against directly changing password field since it gets rid of cryptography built into Django

Comment: I'll do it then. The way you did changed the password, but it changed to something I can't see or either change again.